# Implement overlay-view at the bottom of the screen with horizontal cards/cells in it

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, user-interface, uicollectionview

I have a map-view and a tableview in my app but i would like to merge them into one screen. I really like the way yelp showing all the locations items in a horizontal scroll view over the map.

I want to implement similar overlay-view at the bottom of the screen with horizontal cards/cells in it.

Is it a UICollectionView, UITableView, UIPageControl, UIScrollView or something else?

Please suggest me and point me in right direction.

[image: yelp map page]

Comment: Not sure what yelp is using. But you can achieve this without an issue using `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 1):

It’s a horizontal scrolling direction  `UICollectionView` and cells in it, with property Paging Enabled equals true. you will need to manage the layout of it in `sizeForItem`.

Hope this helps you out